# Concentric pie chart using Google Chart Tools

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-visualization

The [Google Chart Tools | Pie Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/pie_charts.html) page shows an example of a concentric pie chart:

[image]

According to that page:

> **pc**
>
> A concentric pie chart.
>
> Supply two or more data series.

Can someone provide an example on how to generate a chart similar to that in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Do you need to use the google charts api? If so, just create a helper method that generates an image tag with the correct parameters specified.

Comment: Is it possible to give me an example please???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a ruby library that supports Google's concentric pie charts, but with a small hack you can make  http://googlecharts.rubyforge.org/ work. Something like

```
Gchart.pie(:data => [[20, 35, 45],[25,25,50]]).gsub('cht=p', 'cht=pc')
```

will return the URL http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chd=s:Yr3,ff9&cht=pc&chs=300x200&chxr=0,20,45|1,25,50 which is similar to what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will use that then. Thanks again.